# Schematics of this mini high pressure switch

Tags: switches

Does anyone have any idea of the internal schematics (illustration) of this? It seems they've incorporated a traditional one-port pressure switch and tee into a single casing, right?

https://www.soleaqua.com.tw/water-pressure-switch/high-pressure-switch.html

[image]

Comment: Seems reasonable. Might be more integrated than that though.

Comment: i do not see a tee

Comment: It may be inside, that is why i wanna see how the internal look like to know the mechanism.

Comment: looking at its 3 layer construction ... i would assume that it is a chamber with a diaphragm on top of the chamber ... the chamber has two ports ... the diaphragm presses against a switch actuator